# How to find the right route in a RouteCollectionRoute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting, asp.net-mvc-5.1

[I am testing ASP MVC routes](https://github.com/AnthonySteele/MvcRouteTester/). I am having [an issue with attribute routes in ASP MVC 5.1](http://github.com/AnthonySteele/MvcRouteTester/issues/37)

When I have a controller like this:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    [Route("foo")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
      .... 
    }

    [Route("foo")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post()
    {
      .... 
    }
}
```

Then in order to test which route matches a particular request, I call [`routes.GetRouteData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.getroutedata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I get a `System.Web.Routing.RouteData` that contains the route as well as values that should say which controller and action are matched.

The problem is that this route is now an instance of [RouteCollectionRoute](http://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Routing/RouteCollectionRoute.cs) 
this internal class is a wrapper over a group of routes to these two actions. The controller is in the `RouteData.values`, but the action is not. You can get as these contained routes with `routeData.Values["MS_DirectRouteMatches"] as IList<RouteData>`.

In the example given, there will be two routes in the list, for the two action methods. I need to know which of the contained routes is actually matched, so that I can read off what the matched route's action method name is. How do I resolve this route?

I'm a bit puzzled by the design choice of having a `RouteCollectionRoute` at all. 
When routing, you have a route collection, then you resolve the route for a url by calling `GetRouteData`. Now you have one route. But if it's a `RouteCollectionRoute` so it's **still** a collection of routes and route resolution isn't over yet. What's been gained by having a RouteCollectionRoute? Is route resolution now a two-step process? Or a recursive process?

I know I am trawling through the internals of ASP MVC, but it's the only way as it really wasn't designed with this kind of testability in mind. Even simple things like [exposing some internal classes or methods](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1445) would have helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Attribute routing is a bit trickier in ASP.NET MVC than traditional convention based. You can start review from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()` where `GetActionName()` returns null for attribute routing and let action selector choose which action to execute. Then you can jump to `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.FindAction()` that does all magic and finds RouteCandidates then filters them by ActionNameSelectors, ActionSelectors etc.

I've made [a pull request](https://github.com/AnthonySteele/MvcRouteTester/pull/40) with implementation that wraps ASP.NET MVC logic.

One important thing to add:
The implementation is quite heavy with a lot of reflection. Please take a look at how the ASP.NET team tests routing [e.g. in AttributeRoutingTest.cs](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#test/System.Web.Mvc.Test/Routing/AttributeRoutingTest.cs). You can use you own ControllerFactory that will return mocked controller with actions returning their names, parameters, etc. This would be much easier in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

@Anthony, if you only want to see which routes are followed with any given URL, then load the [Cobisi Routing Assistant](http://cobisi.com/routing-assistant) extension.

In the Visual Studio IDE, go to Tools->Extension Manager....  Then, make sure you have the Online Gallery tab selected and type "cobisi" in the search box.  Once you have installed the extension, you will get a new item in the Tools menu called Cobisi (natch).

Choose the URL Mapper, unlock the project if it complains about it being locked, and then enter a URL.  When you click on the Map button, you will see how the URL is routed.  Super awesome if you are stuck with routing issues, IMHO.

Comment: I'm sure that's useful, but won't directly help me do the same in my code. Unless I can look thorough their source.